# How to use an array in REPLACE() function?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have some characters that I want replace them with some other characters.

- `-` => `*`
- `/` => `.`
- `<` => `{`
- `>` => `}`

Also here is an example of a record in the table: *(database)*

```
+-------------------+
| - it <is> a test/ |
+-------------------+
```

And I want this **output:**

```
+-------------------+
| * it {is} a test. |
+-------------------+
```

---

Well, I can do that using 4 separated update queries: *(through execute them one after the other)*

```
UPDATE table SET `col` = REPLACE(`col`, '-', '*' );
UPDATE table SET `col` = REPLACE(`col`, '/', '.' );
UPDATE table SET `col` = REPLACE(`col`, '<', '{' );
UPDATE table SET `col` = REPLACE(`col`, '>', '}' );
```

---

Now I want to know, is there any shorter solution? *(because in reality, there is more than 12 cases for replacing).* For example, is it possible to I write all those symbol in an array and then put that array in the `update` query just for one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
SET `col` = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`col`, 
                                                         '>', 
                                                         '}' ), 
                                                 '<', 
                                                 '{' ), 
                                         '/', 
                                         '.' ), 
                                 '-', 
                                 '*' );
```

There is a function on postgresql translate to do exactly that. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Here I found a stored procedure replicating that function, (comment are in spanish).

http://www.forosdelweb.com/f86/funcion-translate-mysql-704190/

Comment: Not to say that's not a good solution, but it should be noted that you're obviously sacrificing readability for efficiency with going this route.

Comment: Looks ugly, but can easily be generted in a programmatical way.